# Automate asp:Label on Default.aspx page to behave like old 1200 baud modem speed behavior

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label

Here is a challenge.
I would like for my web page to have a label that visually looks like the old days of how 1200 baud modems use to look like. The label needs to be populated by a text file with around 20-30 lines of text. When I say behave, it prints each character one after another like the old days.

I have a client side script, which reads the text file, and populates the label correctly, but all at once with no delay between characters. In a browser, it is presented like a final list.
I also have server side code that works in the Default.aspx.vb code behind file as well. (In case I need it to work there). Either way is fine with me, but I can't get the delay effect that I'm working towards doing it either way. I'm guessing it will need to be in the client side script code.
If I have to use some sort of update panel, or other ajax object, then that is fine as well.

Hopefully I have explained the challenge well enough. Let me know if further details are needed.

Thank you for your efforts!!

Here is my embedded client side script in my Default.aspx page -

```
<%
    Dim objFSO = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
    Dim objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Terminal/GameList.txt"), 1)
    Dim strFileRecord As String = ""
    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim arrFileLines() As String
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        ReDim Preserve arrFileLines(intCounter)
        strFileRecord = objFile.ReadLine
        arrFileLines(intCounter) = strFileRecord
        lblFileContents.Text = lblFileContents.Text & arrFileLines(intCounter) & "</br>"
        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Loop
    objFile.Close
    lblFileContents.Text = lblFileContents.Text & "*[EOF]*" & "</br>"
%>
```

As you can see, the data is all appended into the label, so I could easily interrogate the contents, and do something with it.

I tried various ideas I found on the internet. Nothing quite is the desired behavior. That is why I'm thinking doing something client side is going to be the way to go. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so drop in a text box, say like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<style>
    .myterm  {
        background-color:black;
        color:lightgreen;
        font-family:'Courier New';
    }
</style>

    <div style="padding:35px">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="start"
            OnClientClick="mystart();return false;"/>
        <br />
        <br />


        <asp:HiddenField ID="hText" runat="server" 
            ClientIDMode="Static"/>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Height="400px" 
            Width="600px"
            CssClass="myterm">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <script>
        var iPtr = 0    // charcter pointer
        var iMax = 0    // max char
        var myTimer     // timer var
        var tbox1 = $('#TextBox1')
        var myText = $('#hText').val()
        var c = "█"

        function mystart() {
            // Your code here.
            iPtr = 0
            iMax = myText.length
            // tbox1.val(myText)
            tbox1.val(c)
            myTimer = setInterval(MyTick, 100)
        }

        function MyTick() {
            console.log(iPtr)
            console.log(myText.substr(iPtr, 1))
            var myLen = tbox1.val().length
            tbox1.val(tbox1.val().substr(0,myLen -1) + myText.substr(iPtr,1) + c)
            iPtr += 1

            if (iPtr >= iMax) {
                clearInterval(myTimer)
            }
        }


    </script>
```

and our code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadText()
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadText()

    Dim sFile As String = "c:\test\matrix.txt"
    Dim sTextBuf As String = File.ReadAllText(sFile)

    hText.Value = sTextBuf

End Sub
```

And the result looks like this;

[image]

the above does assume jQuery.

## Edit: Same code without jQuery

Here is the same code, no jQuery required.

```
<script>
    var iPtr = 0    // charcter pointer
    var iMax = 0    // max char
    var myTimer     // timer var
    var c = "█"
    var tbox1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1')
    var myText = document.getElementById('hText').value

    function mystart() {
        iPtr = 0
        iMax = myText.length
        tbox1.value = c
        myTimer = setInterval(MyTick, 100)
    }

    function MyTick() {
        var myLen = tbox1.value.length
        tbox1.value = (tbox1.value.substr(0,myLen -1) + myText.substr(iPtr,1) + c)
        iPtr += 1

        if (iPtr >= iMax) {
            clearInterval(myTimer)
        }
    }
</script>
```

## Edit: Have code run without button click

to run code after page loads, then simple add a window.onload code stub to the JavaScript code.

Say, like this:

```
<script>
    var iPtr = 0    // charcter pointer
    var iMax = 0    // max char
    var myTimer     // timer var
    var c = "█"
    var tbox1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1')
    var myText = document.getElementById('hText').value

    function mystart() {
        iPtr = 0
        iMax = myText.length
        tbox1.value = c
        myTimer = setInterval(MyTick, 100)
    }

    function MyTick() {
        var myLen = tbox1.value.length
        tbox1.value = (tbox1.value.substr(0,myLen -1) + myText.substr(iPtr,1) + c)
        iPtr += 1

        if (iPtr >= iMax) {
            clearInterval(myTimer)
        }
    }


    window.onload = function () {
        mystart()
    }


</script>
```

So, with above, after the page loads, the function should run. The code behind that loads up the text can remain as posted here.

Comment: OH nice!! 
That is the behavior I am looking for. That's kind of involved though. I would have that there would be a more straightforward way than using jQuery outside source library. Maybe a way to read the string of characters in the label, and display them like that in another object..??

Does give me an option to try though. Thanks!

Any others out here with idea's?

Comment: there is ONLY 2 lines of code in above that uses jQuery. (maybe you don't know what jQuery is and does?). jQuery is just a "helper" library that makes selecting of controls in the markup a wee bit less work - really does not do anything more. I about to have coffee, but wait 5-10 minutes, and I post the above code as JavaScript without any jQuery required.

Comment: so, see the updated code. >> "maybe read string of chars in a label".  --- Gee, what do you think I did here? In place of a label, I just used a hidden field, so you don't see that text on the page. Then we loop over the string, grabbing one char, adding to text box, then delay. I mean, even on old Apple II basic, that code would work much the same, would it not? All we do is take one char from the string (iPtr position), insert into the text box, and then increment iPtr to the next value. We keep looping until such time all chars are done. For delay, we used "timer" of JavaScript.

Comment: could have used a label, but why not use a "hidden field" control, since then you don't see the text on the web page. It is then a simple matter to grab one char at a time, shove into text box, and then delay. the only "fancy pants" extra was tossing in that [] char to look like a old school cursor on the screen. I was quite surprised at how well that worked. So, I shove in the ONE char that looks like a cursor, and then we grab a char, grab existing text less 1 (without cursor) shove back into text box + re-add the cursor. So, code is even less complex if we remove that cute cursor effect

Comment: Nice Albert. That looks really clean. I'll play with that and report back..
Thank you...

Comment: Yes, it is a great question, since some simple looping and string code in js is a great thing to learn. (do mark this question as answer if you feel it helped you).

Comment: Hi Albert. I was able to have time to get back to this. (Family death, work, etc..)
It works great as you provided. I tried to automate it so that when the page loads, it will fire but was unable to get it to work. I couldn't call the button click event from the page load side. I wasn't able to get  to function programmatically from code behind either.  Any help? (If you have time). Thank you! Ken

Comment: See my edit - it is a simple matter and common goal to have some JavaScript run after the page loads. If you found this answer helpful, then do mark this as an answer.